# C# methood to scrape a line into an array - does not pass the array on return

Tags: c#, arrays

i am quite new to C# and i have been doing my progress via projects with goals i`m trying to achieve.

i am stuck in something rather general and simple, and it will assist me to understand and move forward.

```
public Array ExtractRakeFromHand(string theline)
    {
        int rri = 0;


        var rakeandpot = theline.Split().Where(x => x.StartsWith("("))
                 .Select(x => x.Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty))
                 .ToList();
        var playerssplit = theline.Substring(theline.IndexOf("ers ("));
        var pbreakdown = playerssplit.Substring(theline.IndexOf("("));
        pbreakdown = pbreakdown.Remove(pbreakdown.Length - 1, 1);
        var numofplayers = pbreakdown.Split(',');
        (string player, double player_portion, double potsize, double rakesize, string hand)[] myar = new (string player, double player_portion, double potsize, double rakesize, string hand)[numofplayers.Length];
        for (int iii = 0; iii < myar.Length; iii++)
        {
            myar[iii].rakesize = Double.Parse(rakeandpot[0]);
            myar[iii].potsize = Double.Parse(rakeandpot[1]);
        }

        var values = pbreakdown.Split(',');
        (string name, double value)[] result = new (string, double)[values.Length];
        for (int ii = 0; ii < values.Length; ii++)
        {
            var splittedValue = values[ii].Split(':');
            result[ii] = (splittedValue[0], Double.Parse(splittedValue[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            myar[rri].player = result[rri].name;

            var ppot = (result[rri].value / myar[rri].potsize);
            var ppotr = ppot * myar[rri].rakesize;
            myar[rri].player_portion = ppotr;
            rri++;
        }

        return myar;
    }
```

i call this method via  var thedata = ExtractRakeFromHand(d);

the return is an object that does not contain the "Name" and "Rake" fields.

how can i make it return the array in the same way it was created ?

I tried to add this class:

```
 public class RakeHandParse
    {
        public string player { get; set; }
        public double player_portion { get; set; }
        public double potsize { get; set; }
        public double rakesize { get; set; }
        public string hand { get; set; }

    }
```

but i`m not sure how to use it inside the code to get back the full details.

thanks so much !

Comment: Using a class instead of a tuple is definitly the right way here as it´s far more expressive and readable. You just create an instance of the class within your loop for every line, e.g. `myArr.Add(new RakeHandParse { player = ... })`.

Comment: Thanks ! but it will be only for 1 player, how do i create it for multiple ? (like in this line:  (string player, double player_portion, double potsize, double rakesize, string hand)[] myar = new (string player, double player_portion, double potsize, double rakesize, string hand)[numofplayers.Length];

Comment: It would help with an example of the input string

Answer (score -1):

replace `public Array ExtractRakeFromHand(string theline)`

with `public (string player, double player_portion, double potsize, double rakesize, string hand)[]  ExtractRakeFromHand(string theline)`

and call like:

```
(string player, double player_portion, double potsize, double rakesize, string hand)[] myar = ExtractRakeFromHand(d);
```

Comment: Please put some explanation as to what the OP is doing wrong and why the code you're suggesting helps to solve the issue.